# How to safely switch to another communicator in MPI

Tags: mpi, mpi4py

I'm writing an application using MPI (mpi4py actually). The application may spawn some new processes using `MPI_Comm_spawn()` (collectively on all current processes) and *some* nodes from the parent group/communicator *may* send data to *some* nodes in the child group/communicator and vice versa. (Notice `MPI_Comm_spawn()` and data sending/receving are happening in different threads both for functionality [there are other functionalities not directly relevant to this question so I didn't describe] and performance.)

Because the `MPI_Comm_spawn()` function may be called for several times and I expect *all* nodes *can* communicate with each other, I currently plan to use `MPI_Intercomm_merge()` to merge the two groups (parent and child) into one intracommunicator, and then send data through the new intracommunicator (and the next `MPI_Comm_spawn()` will happen on the new intracommunicator).

However, because the spawn and merge process happens during the program running, there will be some data sent through the old communicator already (but may not have yet been received by the dest). How could I safely switch from the old communicator to the new communicator (e.g. be able to delete the old communicator[s] at some point) while losing the least performance? The `MPI_Comm_merge()` is the only way I know to guarentee all processes can send data to each other (because if we don't merge, the next time we call `MPI_Comm_merge()`, some processes can't directly send data to each other), and I don't mind to change it to another method as long as it works well.

For example, in the following chart, process A, B, C are initial processes (`mpiexec -np 3`), D is a spawned process:

[image: Chart 1]

A and B will send continous data to C; during the sending time, D is spawned; then C sends data to D. Suppose the old communicator A, B and C uses is `comm1` and the merged intracommunicator is `comm2`.

What I want to achieve is to send data through `comm1` initially, and (all processes) switch to `comm2` after D is spawned. What lacks is a mechanism to know when can C safely switch from `comm1` to `comm2` to receive data from A and/or B, and then I can safely call `MPI_Comm_free(comm1)`.
Simply sending a special tag through `comm1` at the time of switch would be the last option because C don't know how many processes will send data to it. It does know how many **groups** of processes will send data to it, so this can be achieved by introducing local leaders (but I'd like to know about other options).
Because `A`, `B` and `C` are processing in parellel and `send`/`recv` and `spawn` are happening in different threads, we can't guarentee no pending data when we call `MPI_Comm_spawn()`. E.g. if we imagine `A` and `B` process `send` and `C` processes `recv` at a same rate, when they call `comm_spawn`, `C` has only received half of the data from `A` and `B`, so we can't drop `comm1` at `C` yet, but have to wait until `C` has received all pending data from `comm1` (which is an unknown number of messages).

Are there any mechanisms provided by MPI or mpi4py (e.g. error codes or exceptions) to achieve this?

By the way, if my approach is apparently bad or if I misunderstand what `MPI_Comm_free()` does, please point out.
(What I understand is that `MPI_Comm_free()` is not a collective call; after calling `MPI_Comm_free(comm1)`, no more send/recv calls to `comm1` is allowed on the **same** node which calls `MPI_Comm_free(comm1)`)

Answer (score 0):

so basically, `C` invokes `MPI_Comm_spawn(..., MPI_COMM_SELF, ...)`

why don't you have `{A,B,C}` invoke `MPI_Comm_spawn(..., comm1, ...)` instead ?

`MPI_Intercomm_merge()` is a collective operation, so you need to "synchronize" your tasks somehow, so why not "synchronize" them before `MPI_Comm_spawn()` instead ?

then switching to the new communicator is trivial

Comment: I should have stated it more clearly: I am collectively doing `MPI_Comm_spawn()`, but that is on another thread (different to what is happening on the data send/receive thread). As a result, there is no guarentee that when one process finishes `MPI_Comm_spawn()`, the data transmission has finished. That said, if we imagine `A` and `B` process `send` and `C` process `recv` at a same rate, when they call `comm_spawn`, C has only received half of the data from `A` and `B`.